# How to inject another html tag inside of $text with Cell.js?

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering how do you put a html tag inside of $ text like this:

```
ಠᴥಠ = {
  $cell: true,
  id: "widget",
  $text: 'This is <b>widget</b>',
  $init: function(){
    alert('widget ready');
  }
}
```

It won't give a good output, anyway is there a better way to do it?

PD: I cannot create a new tag 'cell.js' which requires at least 1500 reputation.

Comment: You don't. If you want components like `b`, use `$components`

Comment: @Hamms $components are for child elements. Not possible to inject inside of $text.

Comment: That's correct, you need to use them instead of text

Comment: @Hamms Are you saying is not possible to inject html tag inside of $text?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying. `$text` is for text, not for elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simple things like adding a bold marker or italics marker in your text, you can use `$html`:

```
ಠᴥಠ = {
  $cell: true,
  id: "widget",
  $html: 'This is <b>widget</b>',
  $init: function(){
    alert('widget ready');
  }
}
```

Of course, if you want anything more complicated in structure than this, you should use `$components`.

See [Rule #2. Use 7 special keywords to declare the cell structure](https://www.celljs.org/) on the celljs website. `$html` is right below `$text`.